# Deploying wars in Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

There are modifications of war files in my web application. I am trying to deploy these war files with help of Jetty. To achieve this I have updated modified files in the webapps folder of Jetty, and restarted Jetty with help of start.jar. Even after restarting sometimes Jetty is not taking new war files. This problem is not consistent. Could someone help me with the proper way of deploying war files?

Comment: Please detail what you are doing.  The question lacks sufficient information to help.  (eg: is `jetty` folder a `${jetty.home}` or `${jetty.base}`? how are you coping the webapp? is it a war or exploded directory? what distribution modules do you have enabled? what version of jetty? and many more missing details)

Comment: jetty-7.3.0.v20110202(Jetty version) is used and jetty folder is jetty home. it is war based deployment.

Comment: [Jetty 7 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), consider upgrading to something supported and stable. - https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html

Comment: Thanks, Joakim Erdfelt. I will try with higher version of jetty